# Python non-blocking socket shutdown: can it raise BlockingIOError?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

If you shutdown a non-blocking socket:

```
sock.setblocking(False)
...
sock.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
```

is it possible that the call to shutdown will raise a BlockingIOError, and if so, under what conditions? I've not experienced it happening, but this (of course) doesn't mean it can't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shutdown.html) and [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) documentation, `shutdown` cannot return `EWOULDBLOCK` or equivalent error. The asyncio library consequently makes [no provisions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/284b787612af2fde74713ade8e6b6a2807d34011/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py#L916) to handle such a result.

Although `shutdown()` transmits (meta-)data to the peer, you can think of `shutdown` as exiting immediately with the actual work being done by the OS behind the scenes. `close()` works in much the same way.